# <script> tag in a js string doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript

The following script displays "; alert(x); on the browser when run.
Why does it happen in javascript? Is it because javascript is interpreted?

```
   <script>
     alert('this is an alert');
     var x = "<script>this is a script</script>";
     alert(x);
   </script>
```

Moreover, I also want to know whether an assignment statement in js is executed when it contains a string having script tag in it (say):

```
var y = "this is a <script>string </script>";
```

I want to clear my perception!

Comment: what is your goal with this approach?  Are you trying to compute a value which you wish to then display in an alert?

Comment: @providencemac I want to study the nature of js with this.As js is interpreted, then why not it prints the first alert before encountering the 1st </script>. confused!

Comment: I see. Well, the browser needs to be able to process an entire <script> block before any of the instructions can be processed. So even though JS is executed sequentially, the browser will choke before it is able to get that far (as explained below).  To answer your second question, no, <script> blocks inside strings will not be executed, unless you run them through an `eval()` method, which is generally a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
var y = "this is a <script>string <\/script>";
```

as HTML parser thinks that your script block ends with first </script>, which happens to be inside your string literal.

Comment: thanks @c-smile. As js is interpreted, then why not it prints the first alert before encountering the 1st </script>. Am confused!